# Rails ActiveRecord Data Profiling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, profiling

I'm looking for a Rails ActiveRecord based Gem to provide data profiling so that I can trend changes in the data.  Imagine:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord
   scope :overdue, lambda { where :due_date <= Time.now }
   profile_counts overdue, :frequency=>:nightly
end
```

The idea would be that the "profile_counts" method would append to some global data profiling table that would trend the count of late reports over time.

Please advise on gems, best practices etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I don't understand the question, but wouldn't a simple cron job, run daily, do what you want?

```
42 2 * * * cd $HOME/app; rails runner 'Trend.create!(:overdue => Report.overdue.count)'
```

where the trends table has only date (datetime) and overdue (integer) columns?

I guess that you can roll a plugin that will use Rufus::Scheduler or whenever gems, but it looks like an overkill to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think theres a gem that does this automatically but I think it would be easy enough to have a scheduled job just keep track of the `count` of a `scope` and then you can query it over time for reporting purposes